# How can I enable _GLIBCXX_USE_C99 on Solaris 8 SPARC?

Tags: c++, boost, g++, solaris

I've built gcc 4.6.1 for Solaris 8 sparc.  I'm compiling some code that uses boost::lexical_cast (boost 1.48) and I get this error:

```
boost/math/special_functions/sign.hpp: In function 'int boost::math::detail::signbit_impl(T, const boost::math::detail::native_tag&)'
      error: 'signbit' is not a member of 'std'
```

(Also similar errors for fpclassify, isfinite, isnormal, isinf, isnan)

I looked at the cmath header and it defines std::signbit conditionally depending on whether _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH is defined.  I ran cpp -dM and I see that _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH is not defined.  Is there a way to enable the C99 support? Do I have to rebuild libc or is this platform just too old?  I'm out of my element so any guidance on getting this working would be great.

Comment: Solaris 8 was released in February 2000, and is now past the end of its support life.  It's pretty much too old for anything today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your platform C library is likely too old to support the C99 FP library additions.

From the [Sun Studio 12 User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1384/bjayy.html):

> Note - Though the compiler defaults to supporting the features of C99 listed 
>   below, standard headers provided by the Solaris software in `/usr/include` do 
>   not yet conform with the 1999 ISO/IEC C standard. If error messages are 
>   encountered, try using `-xc99=none` to obtain the 1990 ISO/IEC C standard 
>   behavior for these headers.